# JavaScript Arrays Issue With Printing Results

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I'm trying to create an app that accepts input from a user then sends it to an array to be printed to the screen. I'm having trouble getting array to loop properly, and print to the screen. Here's what I have so far:

```
var groceries = getGroceries();
printGroceries(groceries);

function getGroceries() {

    var canExit = false;
    var myGroceries = new Array();
    while (myGroceries != 'q') {

        myGroceries = prompt("Enter an item to add to the grocery list (enter \‘q\’ to quit):", null);

        if ((myGroceries !== null) && (myGroceries != "q")) {
            myGroceries.push(myGroceries);
            canExit = true;
        }
    }
    return myGroceries;

}

function printGroceries() {

    if (myGroceries.length > 0) {
        document.write("Here’s your grocery list:<br><br>" + myGroceries.join("<br><br>"));

        } else {
            document.write("Sorry, your list is empty.");

        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It will be easier to answer your question if you can mention what is the current output and what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use another var for the prompted grocery:

```
var grocery = null;  //Add this var
while (grocery != 'q') {
    grocery = prompt("Enter an item to add to the grocery list (enter \‘q\’ to quit):", null);

    if ((grocery !== null) && (grocery != "q")) {
        myGroceries.push(grocery);
        canExit = true;
    }
}
```

In your old code, you were using the same var `myGroceries` for your array and item, so it got overwritten with the prompt string.

In your old code, you were using the same var `myGroceries` for your array and item, so it got overwritten with the prompt string.

**EDIT** Although the above is correct, this would be cleaner IMO

```
var grocery;
do{
   grocery = prompt("Enter an item to add to the grocery list (enter \‘q\’ to quit):", null);
}while (grocery != 'q' && grocery !== null);
myGroceries.push(grocery);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your function

```
function printGroceries() {
```

is not accepting any parameters whereas you are passing groceries to it. it should be

```
function printGroceries(myGroceries) {
```

and use different variable for prompt

```
myprompt = prompt("Enter an item to add to the grocery list (enter \‘q\
```

Comment: I tried that once, and it didn't work. Maybe I didn't save my changes.

Answer (score 0):

Many things are wrong with your code (duplicate variables, undefined references to local variables, etc).  Try

```
    function getGroceries() {

        var canExit = false;
        var myGroceries = [];
        var myGroceriesPrompt = prompt("Enter an item to add to the grocery list (enter \‘q\’ to quit):", null);

            if ((myGroceriesPrompt !== null) && (myGroceriesPrompt != "q")) {
                myGroceries.push(myGroceriesPrompt);
                canExit = true;
            }
        return myGroceries;

    }

    function printGroceries(groceries) {

        if (groceries.length > 0) {
            document.write("Here’s your grocery list:" + groceries.join("<br></br>"));

        } else {
            document.write("Sorry, your list is empty.");

        }
    }
    var groceries = getGroceries();
    printGroceries(groceries);
```

**myGroceries** was already defined, and you tried to access it though you were trying to access **groceries (twice).  Also, you tried to call functions before they were defined.**

**[DEMO](http://js.do/code/30159)**

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like it should. I had to fix a lot of errors. Including two different things that were performing different methods that had the same variable. Incorrectly placed while statement. And other things I'm forgetting. I also changed document.write to console.log. document.write is not recommended. But if you insist on using it just change the console.logs to document.write.

```
var grocerieitem;
var myGroceries = [];

function getGroceries() {

        grocerieitem = prompt("Enter an item to add to the grocery list (enter q to quit)");

        if ((grocerieitem !== null) && (grocerieitem != "q")) {
            myGroceries.push(grocerieitem);
            getGroceries();

        }
        else {
        printGroceries(myGroceries);
        }
}

function printGroceries() {

    if (myGroceries.length > 0) {
        console.log("Here’s your grocery list:<br><br>" + myGroceries.join("<br><br>"));

        } else {
            console.log("Sorry, your list is empty.");

        }
}

getGroceries();
```